# How to customize macOS print modal for an app?

Tags: macos, apple-documentation

Looking at an existing macOS app I see the print modal has an app specific option:

> Don't print bracketed chords (hide [C], [Dm], etc.)

[image: App screenshot]

Toggling this option updates the preview instantly.
Could someone point me in the direction for the documentation for this feature of customising the print modal?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in apple docs
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_printpanel/osxp_printpanel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000862-BAJBFGED